# Re-sizing Trello cards vertically

Tags: trello, scheduling

Is it possible to re-size Trello cards in the vertical dimension? We'd like a visual way to track our shop's job-lot work load; if a card's height was in proportion to the job, it would give us a quick reference. (example: a job requiring twice the time would be twice as long.)